# Mini search only in one category

Tags: catalogsearch, search

is there a possibility to tell magento mini search to search only in one category ?
I found couple of tutorials to get it in advanced search as a dropdown - but i want to specify only one category and in mini search

Comment: This may helpful. http://edmondscommerce.github.io/magento/magento-search-within-current-top-level-category.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The quick and dirty way to do this is to add a hidden form element to the `app/design/frontend/NAMESPACE/THEME/template/catalogsearch/form.mini.phtml` template:

```
<input type="hidden" name="cat" value="CATEGORY_ID" />
```

When you submit the form, this category ID will be used to add a filter to the result collection.

Comment: I wouldn't call this dirty - it's clever.